# What is the result of decodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent(string))?

Tags: javascript

While I was working on some strange JavaScript code at work, I found this :

```
string = decodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent(string));
```

In my opinion, this code is useless and I have to remove it. But maybe it's a hack for some very specific cases. Google has showed me that there exist other programs with this instruction.

So, do you known what is the result of this? Just a slow memory copy of a string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just from looking at it, I would say they cancel each other out and the string returned is the original input string. Unless I miss something, it has no side effects.

However, I have seen code like this before

```
return unescape( encodeURIComponent( s ) );
```

and

```
return decodeURIComponent( escape( s ) );
```

which uses the fact that encodeURIComponent/decodeURIComponent is tied to UTF8 whereas escape/unescape is not.

It's a hack to cancel out all but the UTF-8 encoding/decoding parts, which happen inside the heavily optimized browser native code, rather than handwritten javascript code.

See http://monsur.hossa.in/2012/07/20/utf-8-in-javascript.html for a detailed explanation.